# How to reset the item select on ListView winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a small project where I get some values from a txt and put inside of a ListView. I need to get the selected value when I click in some item, the first item that I ever select, works fine, but if I try to select again, I get an exception.

This is what I did..

```
Json = new StreamReader(openDialog.FileName).ReadToEnd();
                var ParsedValue = JsonValue.Parse(Json);
                Parsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model>>(ParsedValue.ToString());
                foreach (var item in Parsed)
                {
                    var rows = new string[] { item.car, Convert.ToString(item.age )};
                    var items = new ListViewItem(rows)
                    {
                        Tag = item
                    };

                    ListViewCars.Items.Add(items);
                }
```

The List view is Filled.

And to get the Item selected from the list :

```
   private void cartsList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ItemSelected = (Model)ListViewCars.SelectedItems[0].Tag;
    }
```

I can only get the value that I select first when the program runs.

The exception :

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'.
> Parameter name: index'

Comment: My guess would be because your ListView is empty at the time that you try to access index 0.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the documentation on [`ListView.SelectedIndexChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedindexchanged). Specifically, look at the **Remarks** section, which reads:

> The SelectedIndices collection changes whenever the Selected property of a ListViewItem changes. The property change can occur programmatically or when the user selects an item or clears the selection of an item. **When the user selects an item without pressing CTRL to perform a multiple selection, the control first clears the previous selection. In this case, this event occurs one time for each item that was previously selected and one time for the newly selected item.**

I added the emphasis. This means that when you select the second item, the currently selected item is unselected and `SelectedIndexChanged` is triggered **before** the new item is selected. So when you try to get the first selected item with `ListViewCars.SelectedItems[0].Tag` you get that `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` because there are no selected items.

You need to add a check to the top of your event handler to make sure that there is at least one selected item before accessing `SelectedItems[0]`.

Comment: I got the concept, when I'm debugging, the second time that I click in a item it comes zero but the list view is full. How to fix it ? If the event is triggered, is because I clicked in a item

Comment: The list view is full, but you don't have any selected items, because the first item you selected is unselected before the second item is selected. As I said, you need to make sure `SelectedItems` has items before you access an item. `if (SelectedItems.Count > 0)`, for example. What you do when there are no selected items is something you'll have to decide for yourself. Perhaps set `ItemSelected` to `null`?